# rospack can't find installed package

Tags: ros

I installed `ros-melodic-navigation` with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-navigation
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ros-melodic-navigation is already the newest version (1.16.6-1bionic.20200530.114248).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.3.0-51 linux-headers-5.3.0-51-generic
  linux-image-5.3.0-51-generic linux-modules-5.3.0-51-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-51-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 300 not upgraded.
```

I can find the navigation package  with:

```
$ apt list | grep navigation
...
ros-melodic-navigation/bionic,now 1.16.6-1bionic.20200530.114248 amd64 [installed]
...
```

But when I try it with `rospack`, I get an error

```
rospack find navigation
[rospack] Error: package 'navigation' not found
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Have you tried rospack profile before rospack find?

Comment: I don't know of rospack profile so I haven't tried it.

Comment: Please try rospack profile before searching for the package.

Comment: Also for other's future reference you need to make sure to `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` before trying to find a package in the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

generally, I think posting ROS related questions would be better on [ROS answers](https://answers.ros.org)

Regarding your question - did you `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` ?

You can check the package path by `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` , which is the path where `rospack` will search

Comment: I found that it took some time to get an answer from there.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably because its a metapackage.  they might leave that out of the rospack find.
but roscd works even though i get the same error you are getting on a rospack find

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Jason Borne. Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please edit your answer to explain why it is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed. See [answer] for more info.